# Setup Cloud NAT for public GKE clusters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nat, google-kubernetes-engine

I'd like to setup a NAT gateway, using [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview), so that VMs/Pods in a public GKE cluster use static IP addresses.

The issue I'm facing is that the NAT gateway seems to only be used if VMs have no other options, i.e:

> GCP forwards traffic using Cloud NAT only when there are no other matching routes or paths for the traffic.

But in the case of a public GKE cluster, VMs have ephemeral external IPs, so they don't use the gateway.

According to the doc:

> If you configure an external IP on a VM's interface [...] NAT will not be performed on such packets. However, alias IP ranges assigned to the interface can still use NAT because they cannot use the external IP to reach the Internet.

And

> With this configuration, you can connect directly to a GKE VM via SSH, and yet have the GKE pods/containers use Cloud NAT to reach the Internet.

That's what I want, but I fail to see what precisely to setup here.

What is implied by `alias IP ranges assigned to the interface can still use NAT` and how to set this up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea here is that if you use native VPC (Ip alias) for the cluster, [your pods will not use SNAT when routing out of the cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/networking/#google-compute-engine-gce). With no SNAT, the pods will not use the node's external IP and thus should use the Cloud NAT.

Unfortunately, this is not currently the case. While Cloud NAT is still in Beta, certain settings are not fully in place and thus the pods are still using SNAT even with IP aliasing. Because of the SNAT to the node's IP, the pods will not use Cloud NAT.

This being said, why not use a private cluster? It's more secure and will work with Cloud NAT. You can't SSH directly into a node, but A) you can create a bastion VM instance in your project that can [SSH using the internal IP flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/ssh#--internal-ip) and B) you generally do not need to SSH into the node on most occassions.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I was wondering why Cloud NAT wasn't used even with IP alias enabled. Looks like our only option then is to switch to private clusters or deploy a nat gateway ourselves.

Comment: I've only ever used private clusters since they hit Beta and, it's been great, especially with the ease of Cloud NAT

Comment: @PatrickW how are you handling `kubectl` with private clusters?

Comment: the master endpoint can still be exposed publicly, even with private clusters. If you know you'll only manage the cluster from within the same VPC, go ahead and remove the external endpoint. Otherwise, keep the external endpoint and use Master Authorized Networks to secure it

Answer (score 7):

> "Unfortunately, this is not currently the case. While Cloud NAT is still in Beta, certain settings are not fully in place and thus the pods are still using SNAT even with IP aliasing. Because of the SNAT to the node's IP, the pods will not use Cloud NAT."

Indeed, as Patrick W says above, it's not currently working as documented. I tried as well, and spoke with folks on the GCP Slack group in the Kubernetes Engine channel. They also confirmed in testing that it only works with a GKE private cluster. We haven't started playing with private clusters yet. I can't find solid documentation on this simple question: If I create a private cluster, can I still have public K8S services (aka load balancers) in that cluster? All of the docs about private GKE clusters indicate you don't want any external traffic coming in, but we're running production Internet-facing services on our GKE clusters.

I filed a ticket with GCP support about the Cloud NAT issue, and here's what they said:

> "I have been reviewing your configuration and the reason that Cloud NAT is not working is because your cluster is not private.
> To use Cloud NAT with GKE you have to create a private cluster. In the non-private cluster the public IP addresses of the cluster are used for communication between the master and the nodes. That’s why GKE is not taking into consideration the Cloud NAT configuration you have.
> Creating a private cluster will allow you to combine Cloud NAT and GKE.
>
> I understand this is not very clear from our documentation and I have reported this to be clarified and explained exactly how it is supposed to work."

I responded asking them to please make it work as documented, rather than changing their documentation. I'm waiting for an update from them...

Comment: Responding to my own answer's internal question here for others to find:
The GCP Slack Kubernetes channel answered/confirmed my question: "Yes. We have internet facing service type LB's in our private clusters.

In that case, I'm going to move all of our GKE clusters to be private clusters ASAP. I'd recommend you do the same, Sylvain.

Comment: Confirmed, I just rebuilt the GKE cluster in one of our development environments in "private cluster" mode (we use Terraform for all of this), and indeed: The nodes have no more public IPs, I was able to map the static public IP's they formerly used to our Cloud NAT profile instead, and now the nodes and PODs on them all get NAT'd to the Cloud NAT IP pool on outbound! Cool!

Comment: Do you guys know if something changed in 2019? :)

Answer (score 7):

Using google's Cloud NAT with public GKE clusters works!

First a cloud NAT gateway and router needs to be setup using a reserved external IP.

Once that's done the `ip-masq-agent` configuration needs to be changed to **not** masquerade the pod IPs for the external IPs that are the target of requests from inside the cluster. Changing the configuration is done in the `nonMasqueradeCidrs` list in the ConfigMap for the ip-masq-agent.

The way this works is that for every outgoing requests to an IP in the `nonMasqueradeCidrs` list IP masquerading is not done. So the requests does not seem to originate from the node IP but from the pod IP. This internal IP is then automatically NATed by the Cloud NAT gateway/router. The result is that the request seems to originate from the (stable) IP of the cloud NAT router.

Sources:

- https://rajathithanrajasekar.medium.com/google-cloud-public-gke-clusters-egress-traffic-via-cloud-nat-for-ip-whitelisting-7fdc5656284a
- https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent